# Custom datepicker options in Angular JHipster project

Tags: angular, datepicker, jhipster

I am new to JHipster and learning how it structured and customized.

Not globally, but in one component view only I want to know where to modify the generated date-picker, in this case to only allow selecting a date that falls on a Monday.

The generated component html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="deploymentApp.plan.startDate" for="field_startDate">Start Date</label>
    <div class="d-flex">
         <input id="field_startDate" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="startDate" formControlName="startDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And from the component.ts. The only date related code block:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ plan }) => {
  if (!plan.id) {
    const today = moment().startOf('day');
    plan.startDate = today;
  }

  this.updateForm(plan);

  this.areaService.query().subscribe((res: HttpResponse<IArea[]>) => (this.areas = res.body || []));
  });
}
```

In the Javascript/HTML this would have be achieved with java script inside the script tags.

Where is the datepicker customised in JHipster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add new dependencies since JHipster already integrates [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap).

To enable ng-bootstrap datepicker you only have to change this:

```html
<input id="field_startDate" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="startDate" 
       formControlName="startDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"/>
```

into this:

```html
<input id="field_startDate" class="form-control" name="startDate" 
       formControlName="startDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
       ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (click)="d.toggle()" [markDisabled]="markDisabled"/>
```

If you notice I've added a "markDisabled" property that points to a function of the same name, so in your component TS file you'll need to add something like this:

```js
markDisabled(date: NgbDate): boolean {
  const dateMoment = moment(date.year + '-' + date.month + '-' + date.day, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  return dateMoment.isoWeekday() !== 7;
}
```

Since `moment.isoWeekday()` returns a number `[1-7]` for the day of the week this should disable all days except for mondays.

There are many other ways to do this, e.g. you could use `NgbCalendar.getWeekday()` instead of moment. I just tend to use moment for everything date related for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you wanna achieve is possible since JHipster uses browser's datepicker: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

The `type` attribute might help you achieve what you want.

Comment: So it sounds like I have to integrate a 3rd party date picker. Do you have any information on doing this?